# Determine NSIndexPath w/ UITableView & NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

Experiencing a little weirdness in acquiring NSIndexPaths and was hoping a savvy reader could explain.

Basic scenario is a UITableView, data is coming by way of an NSFetchedResultsController. I'm trying several approaches to achieving expanding/collapsing sections.Eg, table view appears initially only showing section header views. User taps a section header, rows for that section are then inserted into the tableView.

Why doesn't this work as expected? Assume we're passing a viable sectionIndex, and that our section has at least one existing row in the model. For purposes of illustration, we have two custom managed object classes (let's call them Parent & Child):

```
- (void)expandSectionWithIndex:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{

NSIndexPath *pathToFirstRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:sectionIndex];
Child *aChild = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:pathToFirstRow];
NSSet *siblingGroup = [[aChild parent] children];  //assume we get a set of children

//logged here, pathToFirstRow = [1, 0];

NSMutableArray *pathsToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (Child *childToInsert in siblingGroup)
  {
    NSIndexPath *insertionPath = [[self fetchedResultsController] indexPathForObject:childToInsert];
    [pathsToInsert addObject:insertionPath];
    //logged here insertionPath = [0, 1];
  }

[[self tableView] beginUpdates];
[[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:pathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UIViewAnimationTop];
[[self tableView] endUpdates];
}
```

Assuming the section I'm passing has one row, and that when observing the debugger, my aChild and childToInsert are one-and-the-same object, why is the indexPath returned for an identical object in my NSFetchedResultsController different when logged *inside* my loop?

I can think of a dozen work-arounds, but what I want to know is the why...

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the workings of the for loop. In effect you are creating an instance of `childToInsert` that is private to the loop. I would suppose that in this context the returned `indexPath` of this object is quite unpredictable.

Comment: According to what I see in the debugger, my *aChild and *childToInsert point to the same NSManagedObject instance. To my reasoning, when the fetchedResultsController is queried for the indexPath of an object in its care, the indexPath of the same object should be uniform regardless of whether the call for it is made from inside or outside a loop. This isn't to say you might not be correct, it just doesn't make sense to me.